# STI, delegate and becomes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sti

I have some STI setup like this:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, description

  # Basic stuff omitted
end

class OriginalDocument < Document
  has_many :linked_documents, foreign_key: :original_document_id, dependent: :destroy
end

class LinkedDocument < Document
  belongs_to :original_document

  # Delegation, because it has the same attributes, except the name
  delegate :description, to: :original_document
end
```

Now I want to dup the `LinkedDocument` and store it as an `OriginalDocument`, with its own name and keep the attribute values on duplication. However, my approachs are failing because somewhere, the duplicate still wants to access its delegated methods in the after_* callbacks.

```
class LinkedDocument < Document
  def unlink_from_parent
    original = self.original_document

    copy = self.becomes OriginalDocument
    copy.original_document_id = nil
    copy.description = original.description
    copy.save 
  end
end
```

This throws a `RuntimeError: LinkedDocument#description delegated to original_document.description, but original_document is nil`.

Doing an additional `copy.type = 'OriginalDocument'` to enforce things won't work, since the save query involves the type; `UPDATE documents SET [...] WHERE documents.type IN('OriginalDocument') [...]`. This fails, because at the time of the transaction, the object still is of type `LinkedDocument`.

What would be a clean way to copy an object and let it become another one? I thought of calling `update_column` for `type` and every attribute I want to copy over, but before doing it that inelegant way, I wanted to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to add my solution here, in case no one has a better one. Hopefully, it will help someone.

To let the object become another without having wrong queries because the where clause is checking for the wrong type, I manually updated the type column without invoking any callbacks before calling `become`.

```
# This is for rails3, where +update_column+ does not trigger 
# validations or callbacks. For rails4, use 
#
#   self.update_columns {type: 'OriginalDocument'}
#
self.update_column :type, 'OriginalDocument' 
document = self.becomes OriginalDocument
```

Now for the assignments, there were two problems: First, the attribute setters somehow may trigger an exception because of the delegations. Second, the attributes I wanted to mass-assign were not listed in e.g. `attr_accessible` intentionally because they were internal attributes. So I resorted to a loop with an ugly update_column statement producing way too much queries (since rails3 has no `update_columns`).

```
original.attributes.except('id', 'name', 'original_document_id').each do |k,v|
  document.update_column k.to_sym, v
end
```